# Complex SelectQuery with multiple left joins and conditions with OR

Tags: 7, views, database

I have a view and in hook_views_pre_execute() I have to add multiple left joins with conditions. Currently I'm doing this:

```
$or = db_or();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $query->leftJoin($field->table, $field->table, '(node.nid = ' . $field->table . '.entity_id)');
    $or = $or->condition($field->table . '.' . $field->field, '%' . $string . '%', 'LIKE');
}

$query->condition($or);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: inside your "foreach" remove the $or = you're currently only going to get the last $or condition once it exits.

Comment: While setting `$or` to the value returned from `$or->condition()` is not necessary, that is not the reason why the code doesn't work. `$or->condition()` just returns the pointer to the object that is already in `$or`.

Comment: May you show the code that is executed in `hook_views_pre_execute()`, including the part you are already showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was `$field->field`. For example if I have a field called `field_book_author` in database the `$field->table` would be `field_data_field_book_author` and the value of the field would be in `field_book_author_value`.

So the correct code is:

```
$or = db_or();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $query->leftJoin($field->table, $field->table, '(node.nid = ' . $field->table . '.entity_id)');

    if (property_exists($field, 'additional_fields') && (count($field->additional_fields) > 3)) {
        $field_name = $field->additional_fields[3];
    }else {
        $field_name = $field->field;
    }
    $or->condition($field->table . '.' . $field_name, '%' . $string . '%', 'LIKE');
}

$query->condition($or);
```

Comment: Instead of using additional_fields, correct field name can be retrieved from $field->real_name